# How to determine if one timestamp precedes another in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp

I want to add constraints to a table, requiring `checkout_time` to proceed `return_time` and both of these to be before now, if present.

What is the right way to do this in PostgreSQL?  I was unable to determine which date functions were most appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply compare times with each other like any other value.

```
postgres=# SELECT TIMESTAMP '2011-03-11 10:40:13' < NOW();
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

So you can compare values very easily. So with your table, you can add a [`CHECK`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/ddl-constraints.html) constraint.

```
CREATE TABLE foo(
    mydateTIMESTAMP
    CHECK (mydate < NOW()));
```

You can make as many `CHECK`s for the table as you need and add combine them with logical operators

Answer (score 1):

In addition to DrColossos answer, here is the check for the "one before the other":

```
ALTER TABLE foo 
   ADD CONSTRAINT check_time CHECK (checkout_time < return_time)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use the `<` operator?

```
mydb=# select '2011-03-01'::timestamp < '2011-03-02'::timestamp;
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)

mydb=# select '2011-03-01'::timestamp < '2011-03-01'::timestamp;
 ?column? 
----------
 f
(1 row)
```